# How to unlock the Hunting Log in FFXIV ARR?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

I'm in the Level 12 (Gladiator - Ul'dah) and my Hunting Log isn't enabled. What quest (main or not) it's necessary to complete to unlock the Hunting Log?

Comment: I believe it happens as part of your class quest chain.  Have you done your level 5 & 10 class quests?

Comment: I was at a loss in the beginning of the game (my first MMORPG). Because of that I don't know to say what important quests I missed.   Anyway, I unlocked Recommendation, Guildleves and Guildhest (all of them in the level 10).

Comment: The various guilds have quests for you every five levels.  Since you're a Gladiator, go to the Gladiator Guild, and talk to the guildmaster; they'll get you going.

Comment: I visited the Gladiator Guild searching a main quest icon and I didn't find, only normal quests were available. Now I'll follow your advice and complete the normal quests of Gladiator Guild to see if my hunting log will finally unlock.

Comment: Main quests are ones that continue the story.  Class quests are quests that give you abilities and information about your class.  They are marked as normal quests, since they don't have anything to do with the main storyline.

Comment: Thank you Frank. It's very important to know that, because I'm looking only for Main Quests.

Comment: You get it for completing the level 5 class-quest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Final Fantasy XIV wiki](http://ffxiv.gamerescape.com/wiki/Category:Hunting%20Log):

> Hunting Logs, which classes gain access to after their first class quest, are a series of one-time hunts that provide a bonus amount of experience points after defeating a certain number of enemies.

So you'll need to do your class quests in order to unlock it.  It doesn't matter what level you are; it's all about starting your path down your chosen class.